# Change activity int from class

Tags: java, android

I create a class for listener the realesed buttons in activity. But in activity I have the int values than need increment/decrement.

In the class, I increment value every 500ms, and change the textview in activity, but cant change the value in activity.

I have this code in activity:

```
int time = 10;
TextView timeText;
Button increaseButton;

rb.addButton(increaseButton,timeText,time,true);
```

I pass a button(view), textview, time(int), and if need increment or decrement. In class I get the time, and increment it, how I can change automatically the time value in activity?

EDIT: In activity, I have a button, when press it, in class (rb, in other file), I get if it is released, and increment +1 the time every 500ms. And set the new time in textView. But I need change the time int in activity, not only in class.

Class:

```
public class releaseButton {

    private Handler repeatUpdateHandler = new Handler();
    private boolean mAutoIncrement = false;
    private boolean mAutoDecrement = false;

    public int mValue;
    public TextView text;
    public int REP_DELAY = 500;


public void addButton(View button, TextView t, int value, final boolean increment){

    text = t;
    mValue = value;

    button.setOnLongClickListener(
            new View.OnLongClickListener(){
                public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                    if (increment)
                        mAutoIncrement = true;
                    else
                        mAutoDecrement = true;

                    repeatUpdateHandler.post( new RptUpdater() );
                    return false;
                }
            }
    );

    button.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if( (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                    && mAutoIncrement ){
                mAutoIncrement = false;
            }
            if( (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                    && mAutoDecrement ){
                mAutoDecrement = false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


}

    class RptUpdater implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            if( mAutoIncrement ){
                increment();
                repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed( new RptUpdater(), REP_DELAY );
            } else if( mAutoDecrement ){
                decrement();
                repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed( new RptUpdater(), REP_DELAY );
            }
        }
    }

    private void increment(){
        mValue++;
        text.setText(String.valueOf(mValue)+":00");
    }

    private void decrement(){
        mValue--;
        text.setText(String.valueOf(mValue)+":00");
    }

}
```

This code works, mValue its incremented/decremented when release button. But I need put this value into time int in class. When I push play button in activity, I need get a time value changed, and normally get 10.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify it and/or add some more code.

Comment: Edited, I only need change a int value in activity from a external class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update the int variable `time` with the following code:

```
rb.addButton(increaseButton,timeText,time,true);
```

because in Java, **[Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) like `int` is passed by value in a method.**

There are *about* 3 ways to update the `time` variable:

1. passing the activity as the parameter in your method
2. Make a public static setter in your activity.
3. Create a listener to tell the activity about the update.

**The first way**, you can a method with activity as the parameter like this:

```
public void addButton(View button, TextView t, Activity activity, final boolean increment) {

  ...
  activity.time++;

}
```

**The second way**, you can create a public static setter to update the value in the activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private static int mValue;

  public static void setValue(int value) {
    mValue = value;
  }
}
```

then you can call it in `releaseButton` by:

```
MyActivity.setValue(mValue);
```

**The third way**, you can create a listener when the update happens.

First, create an interface in the `releaseButton` class:

```
public class releaseButton {

  private ReleaseButtonListener listener;
  public interface ReleaseButtonListener {
    void updateValue(int value);
  }

  public void setListener(ReleaseButtonListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  public void addButton(View button, TextView t, int value, final boolean increment){

    ...
    // when there is a change in the value, tell the listener.
    listener.updateValue(mValue);
  }
}
```

Then to listen for the change, you need to set the listener in the activity:

```
rb.addButton(increaseButton,timeText,time,true);
rb.setListener(new releaseButton ReleaseButtonListener() {
    void updateValue(int value) {
      // use the value
      mValue = value;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a listener and notify the calling activity when the value changes:

```
public class releaseButton {

    OnValueChangedListener listener;

    ...

    public void addButton(View button, TextView t, int value, final boolean increment, OnValueChangedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        ...
    }

    ...

    private void increment() {
        mValue++;
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onValueChanged(mValue);
        }
        // You can move this into the calling Activity's onValueChanged()
        text.setText(String.valueOf(mValue)+":00");

    }

    private void decrement() {
        mValue--;
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onValueChanged(mValue);
        }
        // You can move this into the calling Activity's onValueChanged()
        text.setText(String.valueOf(mValue)+":00");
    }

    public interface OnValueChangedListener {
        void onValueChanged(int newValue);
    }
}
```

Activity should implement the listener/callback as follows:

```
TextView timeText;
...

rb.addButton(increaseButton, timeText, time, true, new releaseButton.OnValueChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChanged(int newValue) {
            // Do whatever you want to do in the activity when the value changes.
            timeText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue) + ":00");
        }
    };
);
```

***RECOMMENDATION***

You can remove `Text t` parameter from `releaseButton.addButton()` because you are now able to send new value as integer to the calling activity via listener so it can set its `timeText` on its own.